# Lua String [[ .. ]] with embeded functions

Tags: string, lua

I am looking on how to embed lua function within the lua string (double brackets). Just to elaborate my case:

### example.lua:

```
function my_message(msg)
    return "Your message: " + msg
end

function makeString()
    page = [[
        <html>
            <body>
<!-- 
        I want to call my_message(..) lua function and embed the value here. 
        What is the best way to achieve this? 
-->
            </body>
        </html>
    ]]
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Embedding values inside string literals like that isn't supported.

Alternatively, you can split the string and concatenate them with the return value of `my_message` like this:

```
page = [[
    <html>
        <body>
<!-- 
]] ..
assert(load("return '" .. my_message("hello" .. "'")))()
.. [[    
-->
        </body>
    </html>
]]
```

In Lua 5.1, use `loadstring` in place of `load`. Also note that Lua concatenate strings with `..`, not `+` like in your `my_message`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too difficult to do using `gsub` as it accepts functions as replacement strings. You need to come up with a special markup, for example `{my_message:something}` means that it will be replaced with the result of `my_message('something')` call:

```
function my_message(msg)
    return "Your message: " .. msg
end
local map = {my_message = my_message}
function makeString()
    local page = ([[
        <html>
            <body>{my_message:something else}</body>
        </html>
    ]]):gsub("%{([%w_]+):(.-)%}", function(f, s)
      return map[f] and map[f](s) or "can't find "..f.. " function to call"
    end)
    return page
end
print(makeString())
```

This will replace `{my_message:something else}` with `Your message: something else`, which may be something that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an existing templating library for this.

For example:

- [stl2](https://github.com/henix/slt2)
- [lustache](https://github.com/jhandley/lustache)